# 7za method inconsistency CentOS

Tags: centos, 7-zip

If I set `LZMA2` I get `LZMA` and vice versa! What?

*CentOS9*

```
$ 7za a -mx=9 -mm=LZMA2 test.7z *.sh

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,3 CPUs AMD EPYC Processor (830F10),ASM,AES-NI)

Open archive: test.7z
--
Path = test.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 320
Headers Size = 178
Method = LZMA:12
```

```
$ 7za a -mx=9 -mm=LZMA test.7z *.sh

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_GB.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,3 CPUs AMD EPYC Processor (830F10),ASM,AES-NI)

Open archive: test.7z
--
Path = test.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 321
Headers Size = 172
Method = LZMA2:12
```

Comment: If you open it with a proper version of 7zip on another machine does it show correctly? Could be a display bug in p7zip?

Comment: p7zip is the proper 7zip on centos. Just the name of the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in my Kubuntu `7za` is in the same version as the one in question (`7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02`) and I was able to replicate your "problem".

In a case `test.7z` doesn't yet exist, the tool prints `Creating archive: test.7z` and *does not* print `Method =`. This does not fit your examples.

In a case `test.7z` already exists, the tool prints `Open archive: test.7z` and does print `Method =`. This fits your examples. The important thing is this `Method =` line refers to the state of the archive *before* it gets altered. `Updating archive: test.7z` is printed *later* (I suppose you omitted this part of the output in the question) and there is no `Method =` line that shows the state after the processing.

If I'm right, `Method =` in your examples shows the method relevant for the file before the processing, i.e. the method you used *previously*. I guess you alternated between `LZMA` and `LZMA2` and expected `Method =` to show you the method relevant for the file after the processing. This made you think `LZMA` and `LZMA2` are erroneously swapped.

Try to use `LZMA` after `LZMA` (or `LZMA2` after `LZMA2`) and you will see what I mean. Or better run `7za t test.7z` after `7za a …`; this will show you the current state without altering the archive. In the output of `7za t …` the `Method =` line should reflect the method you have just used.

Comment: who would have thought!! Thanks